# processing items in a array with delay between each item in nodejs

Tags: node.js, promise, delay

I have a list of messages that needs to send with 1 second delay in between.
currently I am using this function  :

```
send() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this._send(resolve);
    });
}

_send(resolve, index) {
    index = index || 0;
    if (this.messages.length && index < this.messages.length) {
        if (this.messages[index]) {
            let response = this.messages[index];

            response.send().then(() => {
                this._schedule(resolve, index);
            });
        } else
            this._schedule(resolve, index);
    }
    else
        resolve();
}

_schedule(resolve, index) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this._send(resolve, ++index);
    }, 1000);
}
```

Is this s good approach? I have noticed that node is using more ram than usual when this section is running.

I am using Bluebird for Promise.

---

UPDATE based on @Roamer's comment:

Based on docs :

> ```
> Promise.reduce(
>     Iterable<any>|Promise<Iterable<any>> input,
>     function(any accumulator, any item, int index, int length) reducer,
>     [any initialValue]
> ) -> Promise
> ```

```
_wait(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}


__send() {
    return Promise.reduce(this.messages, function (dummy, response, index, len) {
        return response.send().then(() => {
            return this._wait(1000);
        }).catch(() => {
            //don't care about a error , continue to the next one
            return this._wait(1000);
        });
    }).then(() => {
        return true;
    });
}
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Passing `resolve` around like that is messy and unnecessary. [Promisify the delay](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/231/promises/847/#t=201612301000157150659) and use the [reduce pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/231/promises/5917/#t=201612301000157150659) to sequence the sends.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 tanks, updated the question.

Comment: If you want to exploit Bluebird's sugar methods, then it's a one-liner using [Promise.mapSeries()](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.mapseries.html) and [promiseInstance.delay()](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/delay.html).